# css solution to reproduce bootstrap navbar behaviour within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's navbars are great on mobile devices for giving a native feel with headers, footers and scrolling content, e.g.:

```
<div class="dialog ">
<nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="form-link"><a href="#">Form</a></li>
        <li id="list-link"><a href="#">List</a></li>
        <li id="more-link"><a href="#">More</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="content">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    Un footer ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

This HTML occupies the whole viewport, which is wanted on 'phones.

In my app, on PCs, I would sometimes like this HTML to be within e.g. a map overlay popup.

I could do this using Bootstrap's panels or modals, but implementing this in a responsive way would require media queries within javascript, which I'd like to avoid.

Might there be a way to achieve this using only css @media queries?

In the attempts I've made so far, the headers and footers are always full viewport width, and stuck to the top and bottom of the viewport.

Comment: Can you create an image mockup of what you are looking for?

Comment: @xxLITxx If you navigate to https://treemapp.se/dev/bootstrap/bootstrap-9.html with both a 'phone and a PC, hopefully you'll get an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Is this the result that you are looking for? Or are you still looking for something different?

Comment: Just one bit of html and no javascript fiddling would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://codepen.io/stuntbox/pen/lEdpq), and it avoids bootstrap

I then did the following CSS to get the switchover (telephone/wider screen) that I wanted:

```
.dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

article {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.dialog header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FF8C00;
}

.dialog h1 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dialog footer {
    display: none;
}

.dialog .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

hr {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

/*********************************************************************************
 * Adjustments for PCs and tablets
 *********************************************************************************/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.dialog {
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #808080;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.dialog .content {
    bottom: 3em;
}
.dialog header {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}
.dialog footer {
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #FF8C00;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

I'll try and do a jsFiddle